# increment value of int being pointed to by pointer

Tags: c, pointers, increment, post-increment

I have an `int` pointer (i.e., `int *count`) that I want to increment the integer being pointed at by using the `++` operator. I thought I would call:

```
*count++;
```

However, I am getting a build warning *"expression result unused"*. I can: call

```
*count += 1;
```

But, I would like to know how to use the `++` operator as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The ++ has equal precedence with the * and the associativity is *right-to-left*. See [here.](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) It's made even more complex because even though the ++ will be associated with the *pointer* the increment is applied after the statement's evaluation.

The order things happen is:

1. Post increment, remember the post-incremented pointer address value as a temporary
2. Dereference non-incremented pointer address
3. Apply the incremented pointer address to count, count now points to the next possible memory address for an entity of its type.

You get the warning because you never actually use the dereferenced value at step 2. Like @Sidarth says, you'll need parenthesis to force the order of evaluation:

```
 (*ptr)++
```

Comment: I'd add that I always write this case as `++*ptr;` because the precedence is unambiguous, and if the result isn't used there is no need to distinguish between preincrement and postincrement.

Comment: @RBerteig: It may be unambiguous to the compiler but it is still confusing to a human. Much better to use parenthesis as this will make it easier to read.

Comment: @Martin, over use of parenthesis can be just as confusing to a human. When written as I did, there is only one plausible order of operations, and matches the natural reading of "increment", "something pointed to by",  "p".

Comment: @RBerteig: If you are claiming that `++*ptr` is easier to read than `++(*ptr)` then I hope you get slapped down in your next code review.

Comment: I do so claim, and have for ~25 years. No slaps yet.

Comment: I did slap someone recently for writing `!(!(foo))`. There *is* such a thing as too many parentheses.

Comment: @RBerteig: Half a century of Lisp disagrees with you. ;)

Answer (score 21):

Try using `(*count)++`. `*count++` might be incrementing the pointer to next position and then using indirection (which is unintentional).