# Incrementing pointer's value doesn't work

Tags: c

This program is supposed to count number of similar entries, using pointers, but
whenever I type in number, counter is always equal to zero. What am I going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//using function to count similar enteries in an array...
void count_similar_enteries(int array_func[10],int *number, int *ptr_to_counter);

int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    int array[10] = {0,1,1,2,3,1,2,67,65,1};
    int counter = 0;
    printf("enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    count_similar_enteries(array, &number,&counter);
    printf("the number of similar enteries are %d\n", counter);
    return 0;
}

void count_similar_enteries(int array_func[10],int *number, int *ptr_to_counter)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i< 10 ; i++)
    {
        if(array_func[i] == *number)
        {
            *ptr_to_counter++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: @user3151918 That's a bad habit. A good C/C++ programmer will work to reduce pointer usage as much as possible (e.g. using references). It's *much* safter. That's also why modern languages like Java and C# don't have pointers at all.

Comment: @user3151918 - Why make life more difficult than it needs to be. Also pass number by value (do not need to pass a pointer to it and also enables one to use a constant). Also the `continue` is not required

Comment: Perhaps a better signature for the function is `int count_similar_enteries(int *arr, size_t len, int compare_to)`

Comment: @Dai, what is C/C++ and what is a "good" C/C++ programmer? The case being. this is a C only question and C doesn't have references. What are you talking about?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [increment value of int being pointed to by pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655728/increment-value-of-int-being-pointed-to-by-pointer)

Answer (score 7):

`*ptr_to_counter++;` is incrementing the pointer itself, write `(*ptr_to_counter)++;` to increment the *value* of the `ptr_to_counter`.

Note that `continue;` is redundant. You don't have to have `if-else` there. The loop will be "looped" anyway. You can just do:

```
for(i = 0; i< 10 ; i++) {
   if(array_func[i] == *number) {
      (*ptr_to_counter)++;
   }
}
```

I advise you to reduce the amount of pointers as much as you can, for example, you don't have to pass a counter by pointer. You can just have a local `int counter;` and return its value to the caller.

Comment: Does this actually work and update the memory that `ptr_to_counter` points to?

Comment: @EdHeal As he wrote it doesn't change the value in the memory, it just move the pointer to point to the next address (pointers arithmetic). After he do the changes I tell him to, the **value** will be changed and the pointer will not.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Your right. Had to reread it. I do not think that was the intention of the function thou.

Comment: @EdHeal He wanted to increment the value pointed to by the pointer (Which is really redundant - He can have a local counter instead).

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly incrementing counter value at address ptr_to_counter.
You have use *ptr_to_counter++ which means *(ptr_to_counter++) i.e. it is increamenting address not the value. You should use (*ptr_to_counter)++. It will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you require

```
*ptr_to_counter = *ptr_to_counter + 1;
```

**EDIT**

Perhaps this would be a better implementation

```
int count_similar_enteries(int arr, size_t len,int number)
{ 
    i;
    int count = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i<len ; ++i)
    {
        if(arr[i] == number)
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure about operator precedence please use brackets, it will also increase readability of your code.

*ptr_to_counter++ will work like *(ptr_to_counter++) because ++ has higher precedence. You should have used (*ptr_to_counter)++

Answer (score 0):

`*ptr_to_counter++`

means

`*(ptr_to_counter++)`

which means increment the address holed by `ptr_to_counter`, which is taking your pointer to the adjacent address where nothing is stored(or may be garbage).

You should use `(*ptr_to_counter)++` meaning increment the value pointed at by `ptr_to_counter`.